# MVC action returning just viewbag result

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to MVC 5.

I have a page called MyPage.cshtml in the MyController directory. On that page I have a link that is defined as....

```
@Html.ActionLink("Get Info", "GetInfo", "MyController", new { myId = 1 }, null)
```

So, in the MyController controller I have a GetInfo method. I just want it to do some stuff, fill in a ViewBag result then return back to the same page it's on, which is MyPage. But I get an 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error when the page is loading. I'm thinking on the redirect to MyPage it's model is lost. Here's my code....

```
public ActionResult GetInfo(int myId){
  // do stuff
  ViewBag.Result = "this is a test";
  return this.View("MyPage");
}
```

So, to simplify things: I'm really dealing with ONLY ONE page, MyPage. The link click is just calling a custom method to do some stuff, and I want it to return right back where it was. Any suggestions please?

Comment: I do not see anything about a redirect in your code. Your missing that and your controller/view code where you are getting the null ref exception.

Comment: What is the proper way to just return back to the calling page @mxmissile?

Comment: From your controller?  `return RedirectToAction(...)`. Returning View("MyPage") will not redirect, that just uses the view for the current controller action.

Comment: But if I do that my ViewBag.Result will be lost correct? What I'm trying to do is simply call an action to do some stuff and STAY on the page. Also, display what was in ViewBag.Result. @mxmissile

Comment: You are correct, for that you want to use `TempData["Result"] = "this is a test" ` in your action, then `@TempDate["Result"]` in your View "MyPage" to follow your example.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my bigger question is: From any view how do I call a controller action to perform stuff and stay on the same page (with the viewmodel loaded) properly? @mxmissile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

because your view `MyPage` depends on a model you are not sending it.

There are different ways to handle your second issue:

If you want to show the MyPage after executing the `GetInfo` action, your going to want to use `TempData[""]`:

```
public ActionResult GetInfo(int myId)
{
  // do stuff
  TempData["Result"] = "this is a test";
  return RedirectToAction("MyPage");
}
```

And then in your `MyPage` view:

```
@TempData["Result"]
```

Another (less desirable) option is to populate the MyPage's model and return it like you did originally, this does not do a "redirect":

```
public ActionResult GetInfo(int myId){
  // do stuff
  ViewBag.Result = "this is a test";

  var model = // ... populate model like (or from) MyPage

  return View("MyPage", model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Any way to just pass in the model to the GetInfo action so I don't need to recalculate it? @mxmissile

Comment: You'd have to serialize it into query string values, or post a form with the data. If your just looking to perform a background action, so the user never leaves MyPage, you could make a backgound call to GetInfo, then update the view accordingly. You'd have to do this in javascript.

Comment: @WebDevGuy2 you could also refactor the code that populates the model into a method, and call the same method from MyPage() and GetInto() if your concerned about DRY.